# How to resolve designated initialization error for UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, initialization, designated-initializer

I'm new to swift and I'm having problems declaring my initializer in my PlacesTableViewController class. It prompts me "Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer" and when I added the Super.init, it prompts me:

> "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass
>   'UITableViewController'"

this is my PlacesTableViewController.swift file:

```
class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController { 

    var pa55DB : COpaquePointer = nil
    var selectStatement : COpaquePointer = nil;

    var chapterdata : Array<Entry> = []
    var ety : Entry
    var sqlString : String = "";

    var chpData : ChapterData

    init(pa55DB : COpaquePointer,selectStatement : COpaquePointer, chapterdata : Array<Entry>, ety : Entry, sqlString : String) {
        super.init()
        self.pa55DB = pa55DB
        self.selectStatement = selectStatement
        self.chapterdata = chapterdata
        self.ety = ety
        self.sqlString = sqlString

    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        chpData = ChapterData(newEntryArray : chapterdata, entryV : ety, paDB55 : pa55DB, selectStatement : selectStatement, sqlString : sqlString)
        chpData.openDB()
        chapterdata = chpData.prepareStartment()

        println("Testing...")
    }
...
}
```

Here's my another class file called ChapterData.swift, used to open database and retrieve data

```
class Entry {

    let image : String!
    let heading : String!
    let title : String!
    let description : String!
    public init(image : String, heading : String, title : String, desc : String) {
        self.heading = heading
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
        self.description = desc
    }
}


class ChapterData {

    var paDB : COpaquePointer = nil;
    var selectStatement : COpaquePointer = nil;
    var sqlString : String = "";

    var newEntryArray : Array<Entry> = [];
    var entryV : Entry;

    init(newEntryArray : Array<Entry>, entryV : Entry, paDB55 : COpaquePointer, selectStatement : COpaquePointer, sqlString : String){
        self.newEntryArray = newEntryArray
        self.entryV = entryV
        self.paDB = paDB55
        self.selectStatement = selectStatement
        self.sqlString = sqlString
    }

    func openDB() {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
        var docsDir = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("pa55.sqlite")


        if (sqlite3_open(docsDir, &paDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
            println("success open database")
        }
        else {
            println("failed to open database")
        }
    }

    func prepareStartment() -> Array<Entry>   {
        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Chapter ORDER BY CID ASC"
        var cSql = sqlString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(paDB, cSql!, -1, &selectStatement, nil)

        println("startment start")

        while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            let image_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 3)
            var image = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(image_buf))

            let heading_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)
            var heading = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(heading_buf))

            let title_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2)
            var title = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(title_buf))

            let desc_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 4)
            var description = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(desc_buf))

            entryV = Entry(image: image!, heading: heading!, title: title!, desc: description!)
            newEntryArray.append(entryV)
        }
        println("select statement successful executed")
        return newEntryArray
    }

}
```

Comment: The rules are complicated but obvious once you understand them. Read the Swift language book. It explains it all.

Comment: I've looked over your file, your designated initializer issue IS resolved, however this caused another error: Property 'self.et' not initialized at super.init call. So your ety: Entry needs to be initialized properly. You should probably ask a new question regarding this as it's general practice to ask one question per post.

Comment: So now the problem left is just properly initialize my ety: Entry, can I continue with the codes I've shared with you(to debug)?
And thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 9):

The `init` mess is a known limitation of the ObjC <-> Swift bridging.

One way to work around this is to delegate to `super`'s `init(nibName:bundle:)` initializer.

```
class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController { 

    var chapterdata: [Entry]
    var chpData: ChapterData?
    var ety: Entry
    var pa55DB: COpaquePointer
    var selectStatement: COpaquePointer
    var sqlString: String


    init(pa55DB: COpaquePointer, selectStatement: COpaquePointer, chapterdata: [Entry], ety: Entry, sqlString: String) {
        self.pa55DB = pa55DB
        self.selectStatement = selectStatement
        self.chapterdata = chapterdata
        self.ety = ety
        self.sqlString = sqlString

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }


    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // …
}
```

Comment: My Build success, however, when i run my project, there is a fatal error saying init(coder:) has not been implemented. 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Are you loading the view controller from a storyboard or nib/xib file? If so then you'll also have to implement `required init(coder: NSCoder)` properly which is currently not implemented.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the view controller from my storyboard. How do I implement the required init(coder: NSCoder), is there any references I can look at to follow?

Comment: Warning: May cause unwanted side effects. For instance, I pushed a `UITableViewController` using @fluidsonic's hack and the `UITableView` was all messed up. It's `UITableViewSectionHeaders`'s were sized all wrong and  the section header font was different. Be careful using this.

Answer (score 2):

See if this resolves your issue:

```
override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
}

init(pa55DB : COpaquePointer,selectStatement : COpaquePointer, chapterdata : Array<Entry>, ety : Entry, sqlString : String) {
    super.init(style: UITableView.Style.plain)
    self.pa55DB = pa55DB
    self.selectStatement = selectStatement
    self.chapterdata = chapterdata
    self.ety = ety
    self.sqlString = sqlString

}
```

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewController/initWithStyle:)

From the Swift Programming Language Guide:

> Designated initializers are the primary initializers for a class. A
>   designated initializer fully initializes all properties introduced by
>   that class and calls an appropriate superclass initializer to continue
>   the initialization process up the superclass chain.

[[read more]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

---

**Update:**

The above code actually resolves the issue with your designated initializer. You now need to properly initialize your self.ety property.

Comment: override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
        
    }
//error: Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer    

init(pa55DB : COpaquePointer,selectStatement : COpaquePointer, chapterdata : Array<Entry>, ety : Entry, sqlString : String) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        self.pa55DB = pa55DB
        self.selectStatement = selectStatement
        self.chapterdata = chapterdata
        self.ety = ety
        self.sqlString = sqlString
        
    }
//error at super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain) -> Property 'self.et' not initialized at super.init call

Comment: you'll need to update your super.init in your initializer as well, add super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain) to your init(pa55DB...

Comment: sorry, but isn't super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain) already added in the code you showed above?

Comment: give me a moment, i finding how to upload my project to github. :(

Comment: sir, can I have you email to share the folder with you?

Comment: Done, I've just finished added all the files in

Comment: what's the project name, you're not making it simple for me, you've got nearly 10 projects in that folder

Comment: maintpt2 that the project name. Sry for that. I'll reput the project individually to the share folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController { 

   var chapterdata: [Entry]
   var chpData: ChapterData?
   var ety: Entry
   var pa55DB: COpaquePointer
   var selectStatement: COpaquePointer
   var sqlString: String


   convenience init(pa55DB: COpaquePointer, selectStatement: COpaquePointer, chapterdata: [Entry], ety: Entry, sqlString: String) {
       self.init()

       self.pa55DB = pa55DB
       self.selectStatement = selectStatement
       self.chapterdata = chapterdata
       self.ety = ety
       self.sqlString = sqlString

   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }

   // …
}
```

Answer (score -1):

UITableViewController isn't anything good for advanced use cases. You can always subclass `UIViewController` and put an `UITableView` property in it, just like this:

```
class PlacesTableViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)

    override func loadView() {
        view = tableView
    }

    // Custom designated initializer
    init(pa55DB : COpaquePointer,selectStatement : COpaquePointer, chapterdata : Array<Entry>, ety : Entry, sqlString : String) {
        // setting up these properties
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)  // designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'"
    }
}
```

And it works like `UITableViewController`.

Other utilities `UITableViewController` provides, like `refreshControl` you can also set one for yourself, like `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` mechanism can also be implemented in `viewWillAppear()` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` depending on your needs.

Comment: What, this is one of the worst statements I've seen on Stackoverflow to date. UITableViewController's should be used over raw UITableView's more often than not. Why in the world would you recreate what's already been done.

Comment: Until you find UITableViewController is really a _bad joke_ in Swift, and even _crash_ on iOS 8 iPad. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16621

Comment: That's an initializer issue between swift and objc which in no way supports your poor claim. As someone who's been in the industry for years working on apps with user bases the size of Uber, I will never take you seriously if you call a uitableviewcontroller a joke lol. To me, it sounds like you just flat out don't know how to use it or have poor architecture paradigms. Also, I recommend looking into issue reports before blaming a class implementation lol.