# Working around an unimplemented initializer

Tags: swift, ios8

Note: This behavior seems to only happen in iOS 8

I have a `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    let type: String
    let delegate: MyProtocol

    init (type: String, delegate: MyProtocol) {
        self.type = type
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init(style: .grouped)
    }
}
```

However, when I try to make an instance of the controller, it crashes on the `super.init` line with the error "fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)'".

So far, I have not been able to find a workaround that suits my needs. I can't actually implement it, because I need the arguments from my custom initializer.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316021/how-to-resolve-designated-initialization-error-for-uitableviewcontroller/30328763#30328763) suggests calling `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` instead, which avoids the crash but doesn't display the table correctly.  Several answers suggest using a convenience initializer, but I haven't been able to find a way to make that work.  Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Calling super with nil and nil is absolutely the correct thing to do. You have more than one issue. I'm not at my mac now, so I hope someone else can assist you. I'll check in later and try to help if it's still needed.

Comment: My problem was "solved" in a sense, I found out we're going to be changing our deployment target to iOS 9 anyway and it works fine there.  But an answer might be useful for other people, and I'm curious what those other issues are.